# How to send custom emails to subscribers in Magento admin section?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am newbie to Magento development. I am struggling to find out the mailing section for sending custom mails [eg: Offer mails] to subcribers in Magento admin panel. Can anyone tell me how to send custom emails to subcribers in magento admin side ?

Comment: There's bunch of tutorials how to setup newsletters, but how do you actually send and email to your subscribers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a brief walkthrough of how to send Newsletters in Magento:

- Navigate to `Magento Admin Area-> Newsletter-> Newsletter Templates-> Add New Template`
- Enter the template name, the subject of the newsletter which will be sent, the sender's name and e-mail and the newsletter template's text.
- If you plan to send the message to a large list of recipients, you should divide the list in small parts. You can configure such a functionality through the `Magento Admin Area-> Newsletter-> Newsletter Templates-> Action-> Queue Newsletter`
- In the Queue Date Start field define when the newsletter will be sent. The messages will leave the e-mail server in small batches. Check the other options and click on the Save Newsletter button when you are ready.

And a video overview:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NowBxMXbv2Y

---

<sub>Source: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_newsletter.htm</sub>